# Cannot insert the value NULL into column

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, sql-server

Hy,

I have created the following 3 tables for a database:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Buyer] (
[Buyer_Id]   INT           IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[Last_Name]  NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
[First_Name] NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
[Social_No]  NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
[Phone]      NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
[User_Id]    INT           NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Buyer_Id] ASC),
CONSTRAINT [FK_User_Id] FOREIGN KEY ([User_Id]) REFERENCES [dbo].[User] ([User_Id])
```

);

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Type] (
    [Type_Id]   INT        IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Type_Name] NCHAR (10) NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Type_Id] ASC)
);

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[User] (
    [User_Id] INT           IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [User_Name]    NCHAR (10)    NOT NULL,
    [Pass]    NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    [Type_Id] INT           NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([User_Id] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK__Type_Id] FOREIGN KEY ([Type_Id]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Type] ([Type_Id])
);
```

and I have the following stored procedure

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertCustomer]
    @Buyer_Id int output,
    @Last_Name varchar(50),
    @First_Name varchar(50),
    @Social_No varchar(50),
    @Phone varchar(50),
    @User_Id int output,
    @User_Name nchar(10),
    @Pass varchar(50),
    @Type_id int output,
    @Type_Name nchar(10)

    AS
     BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;  

    insert into Buyer(Last_Name,First_Name,Social_No,Phone)
    values (@Last_Name,@First_Name,@Social_No,@Phone)
    set @Buyer_Id = SCOPE_IDENTITY();  

    insert into [User](User_Name,Pass)
    values(@User_Name,@Pass)
    set @User_Id = SCOPE_IDENTITY();  


    insert into [Type](Type_Name)
    values (@Type_Name)
    set @Type_id = SCOPE_IDENTITY();    

    RETURN 0

 END
```

and the C# code:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("InsertCustomer", conn);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            SqlParameter paramLastName = new SqlParameter("@Last_Name", customer.Last_Name);
            SqlParameter paramFirstName = new SqlParameter("@First_Name", customer.First_Name);
            SqlParameter paramSocialNo = new SqlParameter("@Social_No", customer.Social_No);
            SqlParameter paramPhone = new SqlParameter("@Phone", customer.Phone_No);
            SqlParameter paramUserName = new SqlParameter("User_name", user.User_Name);
            SqlParameter paramPass = new SqlParameter("@Pass", user.Pass);
            SqlParameter paramTypeName = new SqlParameter("@Type_Name", type.Type_Name);
            SqlParameter paramBuyerId = new SqlParameter("@Buyer_Id", SqlDbType.Int);
            paramBuyerId.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
            SqlParameter paramUserId = new SqlParameter("@User_Id", SqlDbType.Int);
            paramUserId.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
            SqlParameter paramTypeId = new SqlParameter("@Type_Id", SqlDbType.Int);
            paramTypeId.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(paramLastName);
            cmd.Parameters.Add(paramFirstName);
            cmd.Parameters.Add(paramSocialNo);
            cmd.Parameters.Add(paramPhone);
            cmd.Parameters.Add(paramUserName);
            cmd.Parameters.Add(paramPass);
            cmd.Parameters.Add(paramTypeName);
            cmd.Parameters.Add(paramBuyerId);
            cmd.Parameters.Add(paramUserId);
            cmd.Parameters.Add(paramTypeId);

            conn.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            customer.Buyer_Id = (int)paramBuyerId.Value;
            type.Type_Id = (int)paramTypeId.Value;
            user.User_Id = (int)paramUserId.Value;
```

But after I insert data into the form that uses the above code I am getting the following error:

> Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'User_Id' ....
>   PLATFORM.MDF.dbo.Buyer'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
>
> Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Type_Id', table ...
>   PLATFORM.MDF.dbo.User'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.

Please help me,

Sincerely,

Comment: I have updated my code with the advice I have received but the error remains: "Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Type_Id' column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails." Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'User_Id'. Insert fails." :-(

Comment: It is fine :-)   I am just tired

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change insert order. First of all you should insert new type

```
insert into [Type](Type_Name)
values (@Type_Name)
set @Type_id = SCOPE_IDENTITY();
```

After that you should insert new user (use @type_id for that)

```
insert into [User](User_Name,Pass,Type_id)
values(@User_Name,@Pass,@Type_id)
set @User_Id = SCOPE_IDENTITY();
```

Filnaly, use @User_Id to insert Buyer. In turn use @User_Id

```
insert into Buyer(Last_Name,First_Name,Social_No,Phone,User_id)
values (@Last_Name,@First_Name,@Social_No,@Phone,@User_Id)
set @Buyer_Id = SCOPE_IDENTITY();
```

Comment: @SocketM . . . This answer is "right enough".  But, if you want to write the safest code, learn about the `output` clause in `insert` (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174335.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

You have errors in your stored procedure, since you are not specifying values for the User_Id or Type_Id columns but those columns don't allow null values.

You should reverse the order of the inserts and use the generated identity values in the following ones, like so:

```
insert into [Type](Type_Name)
values (@Type_Name)
set @Type_id = SCOPE_IDENTITY();    

insert into [User](User_Name,Pass,TypeId)
values(@User_Name,@Pass,@Type_id)
set @User_Id = SCOPE_IDENTITY();  

insert into Buyer(Last_Name,First_Name,Social_No,Phone,User_Id)
values (@Last_Name,@First_Name,@Social_No,@Phone,@User_Id)
set @Buyer_Id = SCOPE_IDENTITY();
```